# iterating through dictionary with list as values in python

Tags: python

Say you have a dictionary as shown:

`d = { 'a': ['s','b'], 'b': ['x1','y1','z1'] }`

How could i produce the following output:

`s, x1, b, y1, z1`

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to explain in more detail exactly what you want. Which "b" is that in your output, since there are two in your input?

Comment: how are you trying to sort them? dict's don't store values aphabetically, they store them according to a hash map

Comment: What's the logic behind the output?

Comment: I am guessing that your logic is to iterate through multiple lists simultaneously. In other words: `print x[0],y[0],z[0],'\n',x[1],y[1],z[1]` ... where `x`, `y` and `z` are lists(in your case the _values_ in your dictionary. If I am right look for iterating over multiple lists in python. You should use `map` or `zip`

Comment: your question is just plain lazy.

Comment: @JoelCornett the sorting isn't important as its important to chose 1 or n from each key; depending on the users input.

Comment: @GregHewgill later response by the answers provided do the jobs. Pretty much the user has an input of how many values from each keys are to be displayed, and it has to be done in a somewhat even fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

d = { 'a': ['s','b'], 'b': ['x1','y1','z1'] }

print([i for t in izip_longest(*[d[k] for k in sorted(d)])
                  for i in t if i is not None])
```

(N.B. `izip_longest` was renamed to `zip_longest` in Python 3.)

### Explanation:

`izip_longest` creates a tuple for the first elements, a tuple for the second elements etc. In this case `[('s', 'x1'), ('b', 'y1'), (None, 'z1')]`. After that it's simply creating a list while filtering out `None`.

You need `izip_longest` here instead of just `zip` otherwise the result will be `[('s', 'x1'), ('b', 'y1')]`.

With intermediate steps:

```
sorted_lists = [d[k] for k in sorted(d)]
tuples = izip_longest(*sorted_lists)
result = [i for t in tuples for i in t if i is not None]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

While Im not stoked about the appending and whatnot, this at least gets your exact result.

```
keys = sorted(d.keys())
total = max([len(v) for v in d.values()])
output = []
for i in xrange(total):
    for key in keys:
        try: output.append(d[key][i])
        except IndexError: pass

>>> output
['s', 'x1', 'b', 'y1', 'z1']
```

Comment: At least catch KeyError instead of *all* exceptions.

Comment: @RobWouters - Actually it would have to be both a KeyError and an IndexError. I do a catch all to quickly handle the fact that the lists will be different sizes and the index is going for the max size.

Comment: @jdi, actually I don't see how it can throw a KeyError here? So just IndexError should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

I think what he wants is **first print all the *first* element of different values in dict & then second and so on until minimum of a list is reached.** Then, he just prints the remaining.

```
d={'a':['s','b'],'b':['x1','y1','z1']}

min = len(d['a']) if (len(d['a']) < len(d['b']) ) else len(d['b'])

for i in range(0,min):
    p = d.keys()
    print d[p[0]][i], d[p[1]][i],

print d['b'][min:][0]
```

Comment: This only works with dictionaries with two keys. And with both lists this exact size. Not great.

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe there are so many answers to such a vague question!  But then again I'm no better. :-) My first thought was to do this the way that had already been done using izip_longest, but I wasn't a fan of using None as a special value-- what if None was an element of the list, after all?

So instead, and assuming the "standard interpretation", how about:

```
>>> d = {'a': ['s', 'b'], 'b': ['x1', 'y1', 'z1']}
>>> [x[2] for x in sorted((i,k,v) for k in d for i,v in enumerate(d[k]))]
['s', 'x1', 'b', 'y1', 'z1']
```

This only requires that the keys be sortable, and if they're not then we're wrong anyway.

(Okay, to be perfectly honest, I first came up with `zip(*sorted(chain(*(enumerate(d[k]) for k in sorted(d)))))[1]`, but I've been using itertools too much lately and that has too many parentheses for my liking.)

Answer (score 2):

maybe `zip()` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip can help you (I know it's not exactly you want, but maybe you'll find out how to get correct result:

```
>>> zip(*d.values())
[('s', 'x1'), ('b', 'y1')]
```

Comment: Best answer so far, but you won't get an ordered output since dict are not ordered by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear to me but are you trying to achieve this

```
>>> d = { 'a': ['s','b'], 'b': ['x1','y1','z1'] }
>>> data = []
>>> for value in d.values():
...      for val in value:
...           data.append(val)
...
>>> data
['s', 'b', 'x1', 'y1', 'z1']
```

Comment: You output doesn't match with what the user wants. See my answer.

Comment: See @Rob answer. I was trying to achieve that using `izip_longest`.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
d = { 'a':['s','b'], 'b':['x1','y1','z1'] }

result.append(d['a'][0])
result.append(d['b'][0])
result.append(d['a'][1])
result.append(d['b'][1])
result.append(d['b'][2])
print(result)
```

That will give you the answer you want. I'm not sure what you were looking for in particular.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly:

```
 result = []
 for x in d.values():
     for y in x:
          result.append(y)
 return result
```

Of course this assumes every value in d is iterable.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print ",".join([d['a'][0],d['b'][0],d['a'][1],d['b'][1],d['b'][2]])
s,x1,b,y1,z1
```

Can't help you much more without knowing more about your problem. Of course there are nice ways of outputting

If you're wanting order of keys and values, You could try something such as:

```
>>> tuples=[tuple([k]+d[k]) for k in d]
>>> tuples.sort()
>>> tuples
[('a', 's', 'b'), ('b', 'x1', 'y1', 'z1')]
>>> tuples_without_keys=[i[1:] for i in tuples]
>>> tuples_without_keys
[('s', 'b'), ('x1', 'y1', 'z1')]
>>> import itertools
>>> ans=itertools.izip_longest(*tuples_without_keys)
>>> ans=list(ans)
>>> ans
[('s', 'x1'), ('b', 'y1'), (None, 'z1')]
>>> [i for k in ans for i in k if i is not None]
['s', 'x1', 'b', 'y1', 'z1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer just as lazy, vague, and helpful as the OP's question.

Also, this smells like a homework question; if it is, it should be mentioned in the question.

```
import random
d = { 'a': ['s','b'], 'b': ['x1','y1','z1'] }
output = d['a']+d['b']
while output != ['s','x1','b','y1','z1']:
    random.shuffle(output)
print output
```

Please clarify your question if you want more helpful answers.